# Spring Stomp + ActiveMQ и новые адреса назначения

Tags: spring, websocket, activemq

Понадобилось установить ActiveMQ взамен стандартного брокера в Spring.
И здесь начались проблемы с Destination Name т.к ActiveMQ не будет работать с **/**
Следовательно, что работало по пути `/topic/action/{actionId}` работать будет только так  `/topic/action.{actionId}`

Проблема в том что клиент - это Android приложение, и необходимо заставить всех юзеров это приложение переустановить. Есть более гуманный способ? Может можно указать в настройках Spring реврайтить некоторые адреса при запросах в ActiveMQ...

Код до боли стандартный

```
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(final MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.
            enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic").
            setRelayHost("localhost").
            setRelayPort(61613).
            setSystemLogin("admin").
            setSystemPasscode("password");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
            .addInterceptors(new IpHandshakeInterceptor())
            .setAllowedOrigins("*")
            .withSockJS();
}
```

Вся обработка получения и рассылки соообщений подписчикам в этом методе

```
@MessageMapping("/action.{actionId}")
public void addMessage(SimpMessageHeaderAccessor sha, @DestinationVariable("actionId") String actionId, ChatMessage message) throws InterruptedException {
    simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/action." + actionId, message);
}
```

Comment: Выкатите обновление приложения в маркете.

Comment: @Tsyklop придется, а перед этим еще одно обновление которое сообщит юзерам о том, что приложение не будет работать без обновления.